# IPFS Http Client Link Access without Token

Tags: authentication, ipfs

I’m following the code here(https://infura.io/docs/ipfs#section/Authentication/Using-ipfs-http-client-in-JS 7) and I’m able to add to IPFS without the auth token in the header (my code below). How is this possible?

```js
const client = create({
  host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
  port: 5001,
  protocol: 'https',
});
```

Comment: You said "my code below" but there is no code. Please share what you have done.

Comment: Thanks @joanis for pointing it out. I have attached the code!